# How do I split and count from dataframe in python

Tags: python, dataframe, count

am very new to programing and python and I am stuck trying to find a way to deal with a dataset.

I have a csv that I converted to a dataframe which looks as follows:

```
| Event_Year | Product name |
| --------   | -------------|
| 2015       | Cola         |
| 2015       | Pepsi, Cola  |
| 2015       | Fanta, Pepsi |
| 2016       | Cola         |
| 2016       | Sprite, Cola |
| 2017       | Cola, Fanta, Sprite|         
|2017        | Sprite,Cola  | 
|2017        | Cola         |
```

I need to count the number of individual products by year. If I split at "," using the split function and create a new column, how do I re-assemble everything so that I obtain something like this :

```
| Event_Year | Product name | Product count|
| --------   | -------------| -------------|
| 2017       | Cola         |    3         |
| 2017       | Fanta        |    1         |
| 2017       | Sprite       |    2         |
```

My attempts using `split` and `groupby` have been unsuccessful so far.

Thanks for your help.

Best

Answer (score 0):

You can split the strings into lists, then explode and groupby.

```
df['Product name'] = df['Product name'].str.split(',')
df.explode('Product name').groupby(['Event_Year', 'Product name']).size().reset_index(name='Product count')
```

Output

```
    Event_Year Product name  Product Count
0         2015         Cola              1
1         2015        Pepsi              1
2         2015         Cola              1
3         2015        Fanta              1
4         2015        Pepsi              1
5         2016         Cola              1
6         2016         Cola              1
7         2016       Sprite              1
8         2017        Fanta              1
9         2017       Sprite              1
10        2017         Cola              3
11        2017       Sprite              1
```

It's probably worth understanding what the data looks like after `explode` as getting data into this longer format is often a requirement of many data transformations, whether you use explode, melt, stack, etc.

```
    Event_Year  Product name
0   2015    Cola
1   2015    Pepsi
1   2015    Cola
2   2015    Fanta
2   2015    Pepsi
3   2016    Cola
4   2016    Sprite
4   2016    Cola
5   2017    Cola
5   2017    Fanta
5   2017    Sprite
6   2017    Sprite
6   2017    Cola
7   2017    Cola
```

Comment: Thank you very much Chris. Worked perfectly and I learned a lot ! Best regards from the other side of the Atlantic Ocean & enjoy the fishing